# Put build number in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get my build number into the web.config of an ASP.Net MVC project (long story, but there *is* a reason)... something like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="version" value="1.0.3936.27150" />
</appSettings>
```

Right now, I'm doing it with an executable on the post-build event by looking at the assembly to get the version and stuff that into the web.config. It works, but isn't exactly what I was looking for.

Any easy way to do this easier / cleaner? Thanks for any advice / suggestions.

Comment: There is a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756031/using-the-web-application-version-number-from-an-assembly-asp-net-c

Comment: I need to know the reason why you are doing this? Is it to change the version number of all assemblies involved in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options here, the first being the one you picked, which is old skewl.  The next option would be to use a [Visual Studio Macro](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/BuildIncrementer.aspx)... this will only work in Visual Studio and on the system that it was configured on.  The next two options would be the best.  Use an MSBuild script as a post build event... or a NAnt script as a post build event to make the mod.  I would lean in favor of the NAnt my self, but then I have a black belt in NAnt.  :-)

Comment: Thanks- I'll probably go the MSBuild script option since I'm not familiar with NAnt.

Answer (score 0):

I had to also place the build number in the web.config before deploying the project. I followed the tutorial here  http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/13/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-5-Increase-AssemblyVersion.aspx.

Since the above tutorial did not exactly show me how to modify the web.config I had to modify the custom activity (code below):

```
 [BuildActivity(HostEnvironmentOption.All)]
public sealed class UpdateWebConfigWithBuild : CodeActivity {

    // Define the activity arguments of type string
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<IBuildDetail> BuildDetail { get; set; }


    // The SourcesDirectory as initialized in the Build Process Template
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> SourcesDirectory { get; set; }

    // The SourcesDirectory as initialized in the Build Process Template
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> TFSBuildNumberAppSettingName { get; set; }


    public OutArgument<string> TextOut { get; set; }

    // If your activity returns a value, derive from CodeActivity<TResult>
    // and return the value from the Execute method.
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context) {
        // Obtain the runtime value of the Text input argument
        // Contains the build number
        IBuildDetail buildDetail = context.GetValue(this.BuildDetail);
        // The TFS directoty
        string sourcesDirectory = context.GetValue(this.SourcesDirectory);
        // web config app setting
        string TFSBuildNumberSetting = context.GetValue(this.TFSBuildNumberAppSettingName);

        // output String
        string output = String.Empty;



         // Get all AssemblyInfo files
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourcesDirectory,"web.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
             // IS tag founds
            bool settingFound = false;

            FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(file);

            // Remove readonly attribute
            if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly) {
                //Remove readonly
                File.SetAttributes(file,attributes^FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
            }

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(file);
            // iterate through all the app settings to find the TFS BUILD 
            foreach (XmlNode node in xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/configuration/appSettings/add")) {
                // MATCH
                if (node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("key") != null && node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("value") != null && node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("key").Value.Equals("TFSBuildNumber")) {
                    node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("value").Value = buildDetail.BuildNumber;
                    settingFound = true;
                    output += "MODIFIED with BuildNumber " + buildDetail.BuildNumber.ToString() + " :" + file + "\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
            // if the app setting is not found then add it
            if (!settingFound) {
                XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/appSettings");
                if (null != node) {
                    XmlElement elem = xmlDoc.CreateElement("add");
                    XmlAttribute attrKey = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("key");
                    attrKey.Value = "TFSBuildNumber";
                    XmlAttribute attrVal = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("value");
                    attrVal.Value = buildDetail.BuildNumber;
                    elem.Attributes.Append(attrKey);
                    elem.Attributes.Append(attrVal);
                    node.AppendChild(elem);
                    output += "ADDED with BuildNumber " + buildDetail.BuildNumber.ToString() + " :" + file + "\n";
                }
            }
            // Save file
            xmlDoc.Save(file);

            //add readonly attribute back to web.config file
            File.SetAttributes(file,attributes | FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
        }
        // Set the values
        context.SetValue<string>(this.TextOut,output);
    }
```