# Get entry assembly from ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GetEntryAssembly for web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277692/getentryassembly-for-web-applications)

There is class library which gets its executing assembly location by calling `GetEntryAssembly()`. However using that class library in ASP.NET web application that function returns null.

Is it possible to get location of ASP.NET application executable from class library which it calls?

`GetCallingAssembly()` is not suitable since the function is not called directly from web application.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [HttpRuntime.BinDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.bindirectory.aspx) - "Gets the physical path to the /bin directory for the current application."

This should return the directory that all the dll's for your web application are stored in.

EDIT:

Ok, based upon your feedback, this might work:

```
var webApplicationType = typeof(MyWebApplicationClass);
var assemblyPathAndName = new System.Uri(webApplicationType.Assembly.CodeBase)).LocalPath;
```

You will need to replace 'MyWebApplicationClass' with the name of any class in the web project that you want the assembly path and name for.

Comment: I needed to discover the path and executable name at the same time. I'd like the method to be generic to use from either win application and web application

Comment: ahhh... that gives circular reference

Comment: class library should reference web application

Comment: Oh I see, well in that case, you have 2 options: 1) move the code into the web application. 2) make the method in the class library receive the path

Answer (score 0):

I think Server.MapPath can resolve your problem, check out this answer :-
[Server.MapPath("."), Server.MapPath("~"), Server.MapPath(@"\"), Server.MapPath("/"). What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275781/server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath-server-mappath)

Also still if you need to find assembly path then you can use 
string fullPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DaoTests)).Location;

check out following for more :-
[How do I get the path of the assembly the code is in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in)

Comment: with typeof that will give class library assembly location. I'd like to use some generic method to be able to get entry assembly from class library suitable for win and web applications

Comment: Oh!! for that I think what @Trevor suggest must work

Comment: I do not want circular references

Answer (score 0):

Try using reflection as shown below.

```
string path = new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).LocalPath;
```

Hope that helps.

Thanks
Milind

Comment: thanks but that gives class library assembly, not the web application assembly

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy I think it GetExecutingAssembly() will give consumer assembly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx

Comment: no, it returns executing assembly which is class library