# Read AssemblyTitle attribute in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, reflection, .net-assembly

I use code below to read AssemblyTitle attribute of .NET apps, unfortunately Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() always return Null in ASP.NET app. How to read AssemblyTitle in ASP.NET app?

```
  public static string Title
  {
      get
      {
          var attributes = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute), false);
          if (attributes.Length > 0)
          {
              var titleAttribute = (AssemblyTitleAttribute)attributes[0];
              if (titleAttribute.Title.Length > 0)
                  return titleAttribute.Title;
          }
          return System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Using your code (http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/170dc91f-1077-4c7f-ab05-8f82b9d1b682.aspx) I can always get the Assembly Title: http://i.stack.imgur.com/b7qGQ.png What are you doing then? WHere are you running that code?

Comment: @Balexandre Try to execute code from ASP.NET app hosted on IIS7

Comment: I'm hosting it on **IIS 7.5 Express** and works fine.

Comment: Note: assuming it's the first attribute (`attribute[0]`) is not that great. That part can be written in a safer way as: `assembly.GetCustomAttributes()?.Where(x => x is AssemblyTitleAttribute).Select(x => ((AssemblyTitleAttribute) x).Title).FirstOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have a type that you know is defined in the same assembly that contains the `AssemblyTitle`. Then you can do:

```
typeof(MyType).Assembly.GetCustomAttributes
```

Note that (for what I know) there isn't any other bulletproof method.

For example using `HttpContext.Current` doesn't work if you want to do it not during a web request (so you can do it on response of a user action, but not from a separate thread, or from a static initializer, or from `global.asax`)

Some similar readings (full of half successes):

[GetEntryAssembly for web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277692/getentryassembly-for-web-applications)

[Using the Web Application version number from an assembly (ASP.NET/C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756031/using-the-web-application-version-number-from-an-assembly-asp-net-c/4803419#4803419)

Answer (score 2):

I use the following in asp.net web app:

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    return ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString();
return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Edit: Sorry, thats just the version, not the title! I combined your version and mine:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute), false);
```

That gets the assembly title attribute just fine. The difference is in `GetExecutingAssembly()` versus your `GetEntryAssembly()`.

Comment: The problem with Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() is that if code are in class library and referred in ASP.NET, a title will always be from class library and not from ASP.NET app.