# Getting the name and version of running application inside an assembly which is not the main assembly

Tags: c#

I have an application which uses some other libraries which are implemented in their own assemblies.

In one of the assemblies I want to get the version of main application and not the running assembly.

The following code returns version of library and not version of main application:

```
   var lcAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
   var parts = lcAssembly.FullName.Split(',');
   var lcVersionStr = parts[1].Split('=')[1];
   mVersion = new Version(lcVersionStr);
```

How can I get the version of main assembly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simply:

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Assembly.GetEntryAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx) that will get you process executable in the default application domain.

And just to mention that this will not work for ASP.NET applications

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4803419/91619

It provides a Nuget package which can provide the main application version for ASP.NET applications or other applications.

https://nuget.org/packages/ApplicationAssemblyUtility