# Published times in Visual Studio ASP.Net

Tags: sql, asp.net, visual-studio

Is there's a way on how you will get on how many times you published a web application in Visual Studio ASP.Net?

I tried to look on Project>Properties in Visual Studio but nothing to be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

applicaiton has a property called AssemblyVersion. Increment the version number by 1 after each update and release your program.

You can find assembly information modification in properties.

You can also modify it manually in web.config.

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
...
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
...
```

[image]

Here's a reference I found:[Using the Web Application version number from an assembly (ASP.NET/C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/756031/16764901)